# Barcode data conversion?

Tags: format, barcode-scanner, data-conversion

I bought a barcode scanner off ebay and, of course, the manual is written entirely in chinese.. I have this barcode:

[image: barcode]

I used a barcode generator to create it and when it asked me for the content of the barcode I was creating I typed in **"a127-137"** and for the format of symbology I chose **"code39 extended"** but when I printed it off and scanned it I got this:

```
435905591573
```

What I want, is to be able to scan a barcode and get back the number/letter string that is below it. I'm trying to set this up for work and I need it to be compatible with a program called "Simply Accounting" in such a way that I can scan the bar code on a part's package and the scanner will paste the part number into an estimate in Simply.

This is the barcode scanner I Have: (Model #: ES-6080W)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of the barcode are "+A127-137"

See the decoding by zxing: http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FGy4jN.png&full=true

I am not sure you are quite encoding what you want, but more than that, your scanner does not seem to be reading Code 39.

Comment: thank you i solved my problem after, im not sure why but for some reason my barcode scanner was converting groups of numbers (like 127) into extended and seemingly more encoded values (like "435905591573") but i fooled around with the settings and found out that Code 39 readability was turned off. so you were right! thank you